# Sampler fails due to regex value conflict

Tags: regex, performance, jmeter

I am trying to write a test script in Jmeter the script works fine for a single user, but the same script fails for multiple users, the issue is there are 2 regex one is extracting the authentication details and the other is extracting the jobs associated to each user, now in some of the samplers when I am running the script for more than 2 users it picks the job of one user and the authentication details from another due to this the server sends the 500 error message,

Here's the data that authKey is capturing
**sitecode: 601584**
credential: {"**SiteCode":601584**,"UserName":"ADMIN","FirstName":"ADMIN","LastName":"ADMIN","RoleId":1,"UserTypeId":1,"SiteId":696,"StaffId":0,"UserId":15240,"AuthKey":"1548dbe78e5d4a71bbe8a70112c66eb82899c6d38dd140be91b7cf5610b140617ed460d6ba674d3089c7199941e1342b","DefaultPagePath":"","UserEntity":2519,"TypeOfEntity":20,"Culture":null,"SuperFranchiseId":0,"SuperFranchiseName":null,"MasterFranchiseId":null,"FranchiseIds":null,"CountryList":[],"MarketId":0,"MarketName":null,"TechnicianId":0,"Actions":"","GroupId":10,"SessionId":103807374,"EntityRef":2519,"IsLocked":false,"EncryptedAuthKey":"tNKvRhDrm4R99OCP45Q+uQnSa+CLfm2iLuTG9lCCWo17CRXPGoCzrzj2nQ0nC68IrqkP6ygRH0hQrrdosqmXoYngBxu04l4zH7rNhMZ1bbcK49QKBVQ9sVp3mTUPjzaBU1MH431lTyGCQMfCJafHHxY+XJNSMeTk/CG6m6D47oZW/v0az17IYcNL586QC6Vsm5BGul5U6+c71fSnTQfIdiWY5Ijye2xjDTHN1LZ8u9UGtrShF7zFCm2hkdFsQ2pk"}
Content-Type: application/json
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36
Content-Length: 3519
Host: qa-coreservices.wsautovhc.co.uk

**The site code goes as 601584**

Here's the value of VHC that's been picked it's from a different site user

POST https://qa-coreservices.wsautovhc.co.uk/api/vhc/v2/update
POST data:
{"IsTCO":true,"TCOId":1016590096,"TimeIn":"00:00:00","TimeOut":"00:00:00","CustomerBookedWork":"","CustomerStatus":"","WorkStatus":"","MobilityStatus":"","RepeatRepair":"false","DateIn":"","DateOut":"","SquashedFrogModelId":0,"SquashedFrogurl":null,"TotalPhotoCount":0,"IsMoveVHC":false,"LinkGuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","CustomerName":null,"TechnicianName":null,"TemplateLogoAssetId":0,"TemplateLogoUrl":null,"SAName":null,"CustomerUUId":null,"SiteName":null,"SAFirstName":null,"SASurName":null,"SADisplayName":null,"CustomerFirstName":null,"CustomerSurName":null,"CustomerSalutation":null,"CustomerEmail":null,"CustomerMobile":null,"DialingCode":null,"RoleID":0,"SAEmail":null,"MitchellIntegration":null,"VhcTotalId":0,"VhcTotalData":{"Notes":null,"OnlineAuthAuthorisationDate":null,"FuelGaugeValue":0,"EmacIntegrationInfo":null,"DmsMetaData":null,"Chat":null,"NotApplicableTemplateItemTypeIds":null,"UberVhcScoreCard":null,"OnlinePayments":null,"IsCreateRepairOrder":false,"IsGetRepairOrder":false,"EngineNumber":"","PartsPartiallyPriced":false,"LabourPartiallyPriced":false,"PartiallyChecked":null,"ParentCode":null,"IsTransmittedToDms":false,"YearOfMake":"","ChatStages":0,"RequestCustomerCallBack":false,"WhatsApp":null},"VQCQuestionIds":null,"VQCByUserId":0,"TotalVideoCount":0,"SquashedfrogPhotoCount":0,"SquashedfrogVideoCount":0,"HasIntegrationRequired":false,"IsAutoSendMessage":false,"PreviousVhcComments":null,"ConvertToVideoCheck":false,"VhcJcbLookup":null,"VhcJcbTemplateLookupId":0,"IsAppRequest":false,"NissanRecallInfo":null,"HondaRecallInfo":null,"VisitReasons":[],"TemplateName":null,"QualityControlName":null,"SAStartTStamp":null,"BoatMetaData":{"BoatName":"","EngineId1":"","EngineId2":"","TransmissionId":"","BoatLength":0},"EventsMetaData":null,"Workshop":"Select","DateAdded":"24/05/2021 11:38:40","DateChecked":"","DateParts":"","DateLabour":"","DateAuthorised":"","Status":"N","VHCId":1012875189,"CustomerId":1004437412,"VHCDate":"20210524","Make":"2019","Model":"124 SPIDER","RegNo":"REG55671","Mileage":1280,"JobCardNo":"JC5461","ItemNo":"","FollowUpDate":"20210524","Technician":0,"AuthTotal":0.0,"IdentTotal":0.0,"InvTotal":0.00,"QualityControl":0,"RepairOrderNo":"","Deleted":false,"**SiteCode":601470**,"TimeStamp":"24/05/2021 11:38:40","Altered":false,"ServiceAdvisor":0,"DateWorkIssued":"","DatePartsIssued":"","VIN":"","TemplateId":47692,"Populated":false,"FranchiseId":27,"AuthTotalIncVAT":0.0,"IdentTotalIncVAT":0.0,"LastAccessTStamp":null,"LastAccessUser":0,"StartTStamp":null,"TyresRequired":false,"MultiRole":false,"CommentsAvailable":false,"MultiRoleSAId":0,"MultiRoleTStamp":null,"FirstRegistrationDate":"","NextMOTDate":"","NextServiceDate":"","DefaultServiceRate":0.00,"AgreedEstimate":0.0,"WorkRequired":"","AverageMileagePerAnnum":"0","PushedToDMS":false,"TransmittedToFord":false,"OriginalVHCDate":"20210524","MileageUnit":"m","PreviousVHCId":0,"PreviousVHCDate":"","PricedByUserId":0,"Revisit":0,"HasBeenLate":false,"FirstEvent":false,"RevisitRecorded":false,"UnknownReasonCode":false,"DMSAccountCode":"","JobType":0,"PhotoCount":0,"VideoCount":0,"NextCheckTachographDate":"","NextChangeCoolantDate":"","NextChangeBrakeFluidDate":"","LastWorkshopVisitDate":"","MileageLastWorkshopVisit":0,"LastServiceDate":"","MileageLastService":0,"ServiceCode":"","EngineOil":"","TransmissionOil":"","PositionNumber":0,"AxleNumber":0,"AxleLocation":"","FirstTyreLocation":"","SecondTyreLocation":"","VHCIcon":null,"FastLaneVHC":0,"Pin":null,"VhcType":0,"EngineNumber":""};

[no cookies]

The site code here is different than the one that's captured in the AuthKey and this creating the problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Without a sample of the actual code, we can't really debug it. Please have a look at [how to make it more likely you'll get an answer to your question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

> it picks the job of one user and the authentication details from another

it cannot happen, as per [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

> Properties are not the same as variables. **Variables are local to a thread**; properties are common to all threads, and need to be referenced using the __P or __property function.

So if one user extracts some value from the response another user cannot access this value (unless you convert it into a JMeter Property using [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty)) so most probably the error is either in your extraction logic or in business logic of your test scenario. See article on [Thread-local storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) for more information if needed.

So inspect responses and extracted values using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination, hopefully you will be able to detect the inconsistency yourself.

Also [JSON doesn't seem to be a regular language](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/4017) so parsing it using regular expressions is not the best idea, maybe it worth consider using [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or even better [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide) instead?

Comment: Thanks Dimitri it worked, the issue was with the way I was capturing the regex, I was using property for that, I changed it to variables and it worked. :-)